# An olympiad problem in injectivity include harmonic series

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f : \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{Q} \cap [1,\infty]$ be a function such that:
$$
f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{k}
$$
Proof that $f$ is injective.

I actually thought about absurd and also using the divergence of harmonic series but i think it's more with absurd which I didn't find it.

Comment: Your phrasing is unusual but the solution should be straightforward. Think about what $f(m)$ and $f(n)$ each mean, and how that affects $f(m)=f(n)$.

Comment: Can you explain more please where's the problem when f(m)=f(n) it doesn't mean necessary that m =n

Comment: $f$ is strictly increasing, and strictly increasing functions are injective.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(n)$ is strictly increasing since $$f(n+1)=f(n)+{1\over n+1}>f(n)$$ hence $$f(m)=f(n)\iff m=n$$and injectivity is proved.

Comment: Why it's equivalent?

Comment: Since $f(n)$ is strictly increasing, if $m>n$ then $f(m)>f(n)$; hence it must be $m=n$ to have $f(m)=f(n)$. The converse ($m=n\implies f(m)=f(n)$) is trivial.

Comment: Yes ,understood I'm so grateful for your help,happy Ramadan mostafa

Comment: My pleasure to help you and, God bless you. Good luck and best wishes!